# AHK Multidimensional list navigatable with Arrow keys and Enter

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, autohotkey, arrow-keys

In AHK (Autohotkey) I need to load a list from a table which has main categories and each its own individual entries.

```
blue            red             green               yellow
Item 1 of blue  Item 1 of red   Item 1 of green     Item 1 of yellow
Item 2 of blue  Item 2 of red   Item 2 of green     Item 2 of yellow
Item 3 of blue  Item 3 of red   Item 3 of green     Item 3 of yellow
Item 4 of blue                  Item 4 of green     Item 4 of yellow
Item 5 of blue                  Item 5 of green 
                                Item 6 of green 
                                Item 7 of green
```

(It would be nice to be able to load the table from file instead of writing it directly into the script code. But I don't know which table format to save the table in and how to include it dynamically into the script. But that's just a side note).

The table can also be viewed here as an actual table:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rFDX_XpD0seDHpkvqSHLnE8HwTmJHwjSv_zgaPCqG0Y

**Here is a detailed video simulation (can be streamed in browser):**

**Video:**
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k4JBy9DShBKwQRswdz8Rxrb9wfvXXGmy

The video was made with screencapturings of some lists, which I was able to create. Then it is edited together to look like it's an actual working script.

As seen in video the lists have to be navigatable with the Up and Down Arrow keys. Pressing the Enter key should open the list of the selected category. The list items themselves then should be navigatable with the arrow keys as well.

Getting back to the main category list should be possible with the Backspace or Arrow Left key (as in the video).

Though, when not going back, but instead pressing Enter at one list item, then the script should store the index number of the selected main category and the index number of the actual selected item into two temporary variables. With these variables I have to perform further actions.

This is what I got so far. I was only able to create the lists for the video simulation.

```
#SingleInstance, Force

;GUi Layout
;-----------------------------------

Gui, +AlwaysOnTop

;Gui,+Delimiter
Gui, Add, ListBox, x20 y20 w180 r10 AltSubmit vList1 gSubit_All ,blue|red|green|yellow|
Gui, Add, ListBox, x+40 w200 r10 AltSubmit vList2 gSubit_All ,Item 1 of green|Item 2 of green|Item 3 of green|Item 4 of green|Item 5 of green|Item 6 of green|Item 7 of green|
Gui, Add, ListBox, x+40 w200 r10 AltSubmit vList3 gSubit_All ,Item 1 of blue|Item 2 of blue|Item 3 of blue|Item 4 of blue|Item 5 of blue|
Gui, Add, ListBox, x+40 w200 r10 AltSubmit vList4 gSubit_All ,
Gui, Show, x800 y150 w500 h200, Helper HS

return
```

Any help with loading the table dynamically, or or how to navigate through the two lists with the Enter key and Arrow Left key would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to loading from the original file, that might be an issue. I haven't been able to find anything about AHK interacting with Google Sheets directly. If you are okay with exporting the file to something like a CSV, then you can read from it with `FileRead` and basically do whatever you want with it at that point. The example below uses your file which I exported to my desktop as a CSV. It uses the first line for the first list and dumps the rest of it together for use in the second list.

```
FileRead , sCSVRaw , %A_Desktop%/AHK list.csv
Loop , Parse , sCSVRaw , `n
{
    If A_Index = 1
    {
        sHeader := RegExReplace( A_LoopField , ",|`r" , "|" )
        Continue
    }
    sDataDump .= A_LoopField
}
sDataDump := StrReplace( sDataDump , "`r" , "," )
```

For the main part of your question, I would approach this by having your script monitor for certain keypresses using the `OnMessage()` function and then performing the actions you desire once an appropriate keypress is detected.

```
OnMessage( 0x203 , "f_DblClick" ) ; Monitors left doubleclick
OnMessage( 0x100 , "f_KeyPress" ) ; Monitors keypresses (specifically, keyup events)
```

When I get a chance, I'll add a working example. **EDIT:** I got a chance; here you go:

```
aData := []
FileRead , sCSVRaw , %A_Desktop%/AHK list.csv
Loop , Parse , sCSVRaw , `n
{
    If A_Index = 1
    {
        sHeader := RegExReplace( A_LoopField , ",|`r" , "|" )
        Continue
    }
    ++nCt
    Loop , Parse , A_LoopField , `,
        aData[ A_Index , nCt ] := RegExReplace( A_LoopField , "`r" , "" )
}

Gui , +AlwaysOnTop
Gui , Add , ListBox , x20 y20 w180 r10 Choose1 vList1 AltSubmit gSubmit1 , %sHeader%
Gui , Add , ListBox , x+40 w200 r10 vList2 AltSubmit gSubmit2 ,
Gui , Show , x800 y150 w500 h200 , Helper HS

OnMessage( 0x100 , "f_KeyPress" )
Return

f_KeyPress( wP ) ; 37 = left, 39 = right, 13 = enter
{
    global bLeft := false , global bRight := false , global bEnter := false
    If ( wP = 37 )
        bLeft := true
    If ( wP = 39 )
        bRight := true
    If ( wP = 13 )
        bEnter := true
    If ( bLeft || bRight || bEnter )
        GoSub , sub_KeyPress
}

sub_KeyPress:
GuiControlGet , sFocus , FocusV
Gui , Submit , NoHide
If ( bLeft && sFocus = "List2" )
{
    List2 := ""
    GuiControl ,, List2 , |
    GuiControl , Focus , List1
}
If (( bRight || bEnter ) && sFocus = "List1" )
{
    sList2 := ""
    Loop , % nCt
        If !( aData[ List1 , A_Index ] = "")
            sList2 .= "|" . aData[ List1 , A_Index ]
    GuiControl ,, List2 , %sList2% 
    GuiControl , Focus , List2
    GuiControl , Choose , List2 , 1
}
If ( bEnter && sFocus = "List2" )
    MsgBox , List1: %List1%`nList2: %List2%
Return

Submit1:
If (( bLeft || bRight ) && List1 )
{
    bLeft := false , bRight := false
    GuiControl , Choose , List1 , %List1%
}
Return
Submit2:
If (( bLeft || bRight ) && List2 )
{
    bLeft := false , bRight := false
    GuiControl , Choose , List2 , %List2%
}
Return
```

This turned out to be a lot longer than I expected (perhaps there is a better way??), but it works. Let me know if you're having trouble following the code and I'll edit and add some comments to explain.

**Old code shown here for reference and/or comparison:**

```
FileRead , sCSVRaw , %A_Desktop%/AHK list.csv
Loop , Parse , sCSVRaw , `n
{
    If A_Index = 1
    {
        sHeader := RegExReplace( A_LoopField , ",|`r" , "|" )
        Continue
    }
    sDataDump .= A_LoopField
}
sDataDump := StrReplace( sDataDump , "`r" , "," )

Gui , +AlwaysOnTop
Gui , Add , ListBox , x20 y20 w180 r10 Choose1 vList1 gSubmit1 , %sHeader%
Gui , Add , ListBox , x+40 w200 r10 vList2 AltSubmit gSubmit2 ,
Gui , Show , x800 y150 w500 h200 , Helper HS

OnMessage( 0x100 , "f_KeyPress" )
Return

f_KeyPress( wP ) ; 37 = left, 39 = right, 13 = enter
{
    global bLeft := false , global bRight := false , global bEnter := false
    If ( wP = 37 )
        bLeft := true
    If ( wP = 39 )
        bRight := true
    If ( wP = 13 )
        bEnter := true
    If ( bLeft || bRight || bEnter )
        GoSub , sub_KeyPress
}

sub_KeyPress:
GuiControlGet , sFocus , FocusV
Gui , Submit , NoHide
If ( bLeft && sFocus = "List2" )
{
    List2 := ""
    GuiControl ,, List2 , |
    GuiControl , Focus , List1
}
If (( bRight || bEnter ) && sFocus = "List1" )
{
    sList2 := ""
    Loop , Parse , sDataDump , `,
        If InStr( A_LoopField , Trim( List1 ))
            sList2 .= "|" . A_loopField
    GuiControl ,, List2 , %sList2% 
    GuiControl , Focus , List2
    GuiControl , Choose , List2 , 1
}
If ( bEnter && sFocus = "List2" )
{
    Loop , Parse , sHeader , "|"
        If ( A_LoopField = List1 )
            nList1Output := A_Index
    nList2Output := List2
    MsgBox , List1: %nList1Output%`nList2: %nList2Output%
}
Return

Submit1:
If (( bLeft || bRight ) && List1 )
{
    bLeft := false , bRight := false
    GuiControl , ChooseString , List1 , %List1%
}
Return
Submit2:
If (( bLeft || bRight ) && List2 )
{
    bLeft := false , bRight := false
    GuiControl , Choose , List2 , %List2%
}
Return
```

Comment: Using a different table file format is totally fine. Though I have no idea how to put its content into the actual list boxes I already have. I am fairly new to Gui programming, sorry. Looking forward to your "working example". Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I updated it with code for you to test. Please let me know if you have any issues or questions.

Comment: That is totally awesome so far! The handling is perfect. One thing: As far as I observed it, currently in your version the items of each sub-list have to have the name of the main category in the name to be associated with the main category, right? Actually I included the names in the table only for demonstration. ...

Comment: ...Perfect would be if this wasn't a necessary condition, but if it would recognise its association just by the position in the table. I just added some values to the table which don't contain its parent name. If these can be shown too, then it would be perfect....

Comment: ...IF it is unavoidable to have to include the parent names, then I would need a mechanism to at least hide the parent names inside the item names in the UI. One of these 2 options possible? But again, very good work so far!

Comment: Ah, I was so focused on making the code work, I didn't account for these merely being placeholder names. That will change how the information is stored - probably in an array. I'll try to get something to you soon.

Comment: The new code doesn't require the header name to be in the data. The only thing that might give it issues is if there are blank header cells. Please let me know how that goes for you.